# Casting a jsonb value to timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I Have a list of timestamps extracted from a jsonb column in postgres 12

```
"2022-06-30T11:19:51.459596+00:00"
"2022-04-28T08:18:08.744732+00:00"
"2022-06-03T09:35:55.919929+00:00"
"2022-06-30T07:02:20.773800+00:00"
"2022-06-30T03:53:43.457369+00:00"
"2022-06-30T09:25:30.116305+00:00"
"2022-06-30T07:31:37.690156+00:00"
"2022-06-18T11:40:51.421568+00:00"
```

Im trying to convert these into a `timestamp` datatype.

If i do these individually via  something like

```
select pg_typeof(to_timestamp('2022-03-30T13:44:55.600166+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS'))
```

it gives me a proper timestamp datatype

however, im trying to do it via a query like so

```
select count(*)
from users u 
where to_timestamp((column_name -> 'timestamp_value')::text, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS') >= '2022-06-30'
```

This gives me a error like the below -

```
 ERROR: invalid value ""202" for "YYYY"
  Detail: Value must be an integer.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `->>` instead of `->`

Comment: One or more of the `'timestamp_value'` values has `202` instead of `2022` for the year value.

Answer (score 0):

`column_name -> 'timestamp_value'` returns a `jsonb` value (a JSON string literal in your case), casting that to `::text` will return a text representation of the JSON - complete with quotes around the JSON string value. Instead, use

```
column_name ->> 'timestamp_value'
```

which will just return the text content of the JSON string.